# How to fix this? Cannot show the symbol. Plus, I cannot run the \begin{cases}

Tags: beamer

The LateX does not show equation like I want; F(x)= exp[-exp(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma})]. It appears like the image below.

Besides, my \begin{cases} .... \end{cases} cannot run.
This is my code:-

[image]

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{comicsans}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
    \usepackage{array}

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}
   \frametitle{1.2.1 Gumbel Distribution}

    \begin{itemize}
     \item a.k.a the Extreme Value Type  \rom{1} distribution is bounded and has the          
    following probability density function $$F(x)= exp [- exp(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})]$$     
    %repair this 
    where, \\
    $\mu$ is the location parameter,\\
    $\sigma$ is the scale parameter, ($\sigma$>0).\\
    \vspace{0.3cm}

    The shape of the Gumbel model does not depend on he distribution parameters.

     \end{itemize}
     \end{frame}

     \begin{frame}
     $$
     F(x) = \begin{cases}
     0, $ \text{$x>\mu$} \\
     exp[-{$\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}}$], & $x \geq \mu$             
     \end{cases}
      $$ \\

     where \\
     $\xi$ is the shape parameter, \\
     $\mu$ is the location parameter, \\
     $\sigma$ is the scale parameter, ($\sigma$ > 0) [2]


     \end{frame}
     \end{document}
```

Comment: Does it help to remove the `\usepackage{comicsans}` in the preamble? If nothing else, at least that would solve the problem you have of using Comic Sans `;-)`.

Comment: Your code has some bad practices, but besides this, where exactly is the problem? Which symbol exactly is causing the problem?

Comment: Please make your code example minimal - start removing code; delete as much as you can while still reproducing the problem. Then state clearly what the problem is.

Comment: Oh my, thank you very much. Never thought that Comic Sans would bring problem. :-) 
Then, how about the \begin{cases} ... \end{cases}. I cannot run it. T.T)

Answer (score 2):

Not beautiful, but a compilable version. Probably mixing the first `&` needed in `\cases` with `$` forced ad hoc changes, with many unneeded `$`'s.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
  % \usepackage{comicsans}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
 %  \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
    \usepackage{array}

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}
   \frametitle{1.2.1 Gumbel Distribution}

    \begin{itemize}
     \item a.k.a the Extreme Value Type  \rom{1} distribution is bounded and has the          
    following probability density function 
\[
F(x)= \exp [- \exp(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})]
\]   
    %repair this 
    where, \\
    $\mu$ is the location parameter,\\
    $\sigma$ is the scale parameter, ($\sigma>0$).\\
    \vspace{0.3cm}

    The shape of the Gumbel model does not depend on he distribution parameters.

     \end{itemize}
     \end{frame}

     \begin{frame}
     \[
     F(x) = \begin{cases}
     0, &\text{$x>\mu$} \\
     exp[-{\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}}], & x \geq \mu            
     \end{cases}
      \]
     where \\
     $\xi$ is the shape parameter, \\
     $\mu$ is the location parameter, \\
     $\sigma$ is the scale parameter, ($\sigma > 0$) [2]


     \end{frame}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]